# Bulding Python 3.7 from source

Tags: linux-mint, python3

I am struggling to bould Python 3.7 from source on Linux Mint 18.3

Some problem with gcc.

Am I using outdated version of gcc?

Here is what the configure script of python3.7 writes to standard output

```
./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for python3.7... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/boldi/Downloads/Python-3.7.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

When I check config.log

I see som problem with gcc option -V

```
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 
configure:3909: $? = 0
configure:3898: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Check or update `build-essential` package.

Comment: Hah. That was it. I'm on a new distro and thought I have all the packages from the old one... Literally I forgot that's relatively fresh installation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error codes, it looks like the distribution has not the `build-essential` package.
To build python from source code:

- Download required packages: `apt install build-essential wget ca-certificates`
- Download latest [source tarball](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/): `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tgz`
- Extract the tarball: `tar -xf Python-3.7.3.tgz`
- `cd` into it
- Configure the Makefile: `./configure`
- Compile and install: `make && make install`

#### Source:

[Cpython: build-instructions](https://github.com/python/cpython#build-instructions)